# Populate data grid dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

```
while (rawCode.IndexOf("<a href") != -1)
{
                string[] parts = link.Split(new string[] { "./" }, StringSplitOptions.None);  
                string column = string.Format("Column{0}",1);
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Link","Links");
                for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (parts[i] != "")
                    {

                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add((new Object[] { i, parts[i]}));

                        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Link", "Name");
                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add((new Object[] { i, parts[i]}));
                        //Here i need to insert data into already existing row.
                    }
                 }
}
```

I'm able to create a row dynamically using the above code. But i'm not getting how to insert data into the rows already created. Below image shows the output of above code.
[image: Data grid created using above code]

I want to add the data next to cells after link. when i tried to use the same code, new rows are getting created but i want to insert data into rows already created.

Comment: are you wanting to update the rows programatically too, or at run-time? edit: just read the bit i missed. posting an answer now

Comment: In the object you add, padd the relevent cell you don't want to add with null values. That should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can update existing rows like so:

```
 dataTable.Rows[i]["columnNameHere"] = valueYouWantToUse;
```

alternatively you could input the information in the row BEFORE you add it to the datasource.

```
DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();
row["columnName"] = valueYouWantToUse;
//any other information can be put here too, for each column in the row.
dataTable.Rows.Add(row);

 if (parts[i] != "")
                {

                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add((new Object[] { i, parts[i]}));

                    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Link", "Name");
                    DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();
                    row["Link"] = i.ToString();
                    row["Name"] = parts[i].ToString();

                    //here add all your column values for that row in the same manner, then,
                    dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
                }
```

Comment: Hello Shane.C, When i tried your answer its giving error as - cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'system.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow'.

Comment: updated answer, my mistake. you need to make ammends to the DataTable, which is the DataGrid's data source.

Comment: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewLinkColumn'`. The error i'm getting after using your updated code. Tell me what i'm missing.

Comment: it may be easier for you to add the data to the rows before you add the rows to the datasource. ill edit my answer (will be the second one)